# Apply wordcount on individual lines in a mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I have an input file like

```
LOW  LOW  HIGH LOW  LOW
LOW  HIGH MOD  LOW  LOW
HIGH LOW  HIGH HIGH HIGH
LOW  LOW  LOW  LOW  LOW
.     .    .    .    .
.     .    .    .    .
```

for which i would like to have the result as follows:

```
Genuine
Moderate
Not_genuine
Genuine
 .
 .
```

For this i need to parse a line and apply WordCount on each line,then based on the no. of counts of high or low I would specify the desired result.
By using `Stringtokenizer` all the lines are taken into consideration and also `split method` is not getting the end of line `(\n)`.Is there anyway I can proceed through this problem and get the desired answer

**CODE DONE FOR MAPPER**

Here's the mapper function which i tried to modify with fetching of `\n`

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String line = value.toString();
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
  while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    if(tokenizer.equals("\n")){
      System.out.println("Line ends here");
      Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
      log.info("Line ends here");
      }
    word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
    context.write(word, one);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a mcve of your code ? (or the command you executed if you use the embedded jars)

Comment: I tried out the basic wordCount MR job for scanning but that would scan the entire input file (which i want to scan one line and generate output) Further I even tried with NLineInputformat but couldnt set a mapper for the same.

Comment: @TAKZO Is your problem with new line? it should automatically take the new line when it detects the line break if you are using textinputformat. You can go with split method and separated by some delimiter.

Comment: This is my final code http://pastebin.com/mEbw6Jei Is there any efficient way to make the program run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is your input file.

Use below code to check your input file is correct or not.

```
public static void main(String agr[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "yourfilelocation"));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

After that you can write logic for counting the distinct words in Mapper.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So this is what I did http://pastebin.com/mEbw6Jei, and I achieved the desired output but the only problem is that I am getting line^2 output values i.e. For 8 lines of input file I get a set of 8 lines of output which is repeated 8 times.Can't figure out what's actually the problem.Also is there any scope of optimization of this code

Comment: I just looked into it. just try to change                                                                                                 private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);                    and                  change this to context.write(word, one);

Comment: well I dont need a count value for the results hence context.write(word, null) also how does that make it repeat it line square times the input?

Comment: As I see in your code  there is no need to read your input file into mapper code again.TextInputFormat does for you. for more details go through this [link]( http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount) .   Just remove reading of input file from your map method of mapper code.

Comment: The input value of each map() method, assuming a TextInputFormat is used, is a single line.

Comment: no doubt value.toString() will get me all of the lines but how do i detect a new line which br.readline() does for me?

Comment: value.toString will give you line by line record. Entire Map method runs on one line then second line and goes on... Go through below [link] (https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html).

Comment: OK removed the while loop iterating the input file in the mapper and its running as required.Thnak you all for your help , is there any optimisation which can be done to improve efficiency of the program

Comment: for splitting use  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html.   accept the answer so that it could help other also.

Comment: Go through below link: (http://www.programcreek.com/2013/10/google-guava-splitter-example/)

Answer (score 0):

In your mapper class you can have logic for counting the distinct words using a hashset kind of mechanism. So you dont need a reducer.

Answer (score 0):

The input `value` of each map() method, assuming a TextInputFormat is used, is a single line. Therefore, there is no point in having a newline character at the end. That's why you don't see any message in your `log`.

As Karthik suggests, you don't need a reducer for this. All you need is aggregate the number of 'HIGH', 'LOW' and 'MOD' per input `value` (i.e., line) and emit your classification ('Genuine', 'Moderate', 'Not-genuine') directly from the mapper.